# Why would the breaker be tripping after removing a ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I removed a ceiling fan and capped off both wires but my circuit breaker trips. Is it possible that the fan was in a pathway with some thing else? If so, do I just connect those wires together? There are two white wires and one black wire.

Comment: Did you cap them together?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you capped 2 whites together, which would be logical.

However, you've probably discovered a situation where one of the whites is a switched hot, improperly labeled (i.e. not labeled).

Try putting a cap on each wire by itself.

It's unlikely that putting a break in a circuit would cause a trip.  It's the opposite problem, a short that causes a trip.